# Bitcoin mining in 2011 recovery

Tags: mining-pools, wallet-recovery, recover-private-key

Help me to understand. in 2011 he tried to mine bitcoin. I can't remember exactly how I did it. I accidentally found these folders where did I get them from and what should I do with them?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an item named multibit.

There used to be a wallet named Multibit

It was discontinued and replaced by a product named Multibit HD

The Multibit HD product was then discontinued and the business closed. This happened many years ago.

If you [search this website for "multibit"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multibit) you will find answers to questions about recovering control over money by transferring Multibit wallet contents (keys) into a different Wallet application.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're wondering whether you've successfully mined BTC as far back as 2011 and would like to recover your funds, there could be a way. However, you would need to remember the password that you created when you first used the Multibit classic wallet. If you do remember the password, you can then check the 'key-backup folder' for key files that have names which look like 'walletname-20140407200768.key.'

If you have these two components, you can recover your address and the private key that controls your wallet using various open-source scripts like [FinderOuter](https://github.com/Coding-Enthusiast/FinderOuter) and [BTCrecovery](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover).